# Can we generate keys on server side and sign them there

Tags: java, jquery, fine-uploader

I want to implement image uploading in my web application which has backend in java and frontend in javasciprt/jquery/html/css and uploading on amazon s3.

I can see Fine-uploader generating a highly randomized key for a file and get that key signed by passing it to signature end point (along with some more headers).

My question is, what if somebody send some other key to signature end point and upload file with that key; in a way, he can try overwriting my already placed file.

How can I implement following logic in fine-uploader-

1. Fine uploader hit end point for signature
2. I generate some randomized key on server (sign that key and other headers) and pass signature, policy and key back to the client
3. Now on same key I do upload and bookeeping

please excuse me for typos and my bad english

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why do you want to do all of this exactly? As long as your server doesn't just blindly sign requests, and it actually examines the policy or headers string before signing, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: How my backend server will be able to check filename, if it is already there in bucket ??suppose a file with name xyz.txt is already there in my bucket.
and some one from client send xyz.txt to server for signing.do you expect me to check my whole data base to determine if xyz.txt is aready saved and not sign such request??

i want to prevent hacker from  overriding my already saved files

Comment: my all files are well exposed so anyone can see already saved names or key

Comment: Simple - use the S3 API to check if the file already exists. Better yet, don't do anything and simply name the files according to the UUID assigned by Fine Uploader.

Answer (score 1):

While your initial question is a bit unclear, in your comments you have expressed a desire to ensure a user does not tamper with the request/policy, perhaps in an attempt to upload a file with a duplicate name. If you'd like to prevent this, simply query your database (or your bucket using the S3 API) server-side as part of handling the signature POST from Fine Uploader. If a file by that name already exists, then return a 500 response with a JSON message body like this: `{"invalid": true}`. This signals to Fine Uploader that the policy or request headers are invalid and the upload will be canceled.

Comment: Can't i generate some random uuid on server side and send in the response of signature request. and onwards that uuid  is saved as file name in bucket ??is  there any way to do the same

Comment: No, not at the moment. If you'd prefer to generate a name based on some server-state or logic, you can override the `objectProperties.key` function to make an ajax request to your server, retrieve the name, and then resolve the promise with the new name. Either way, if you're really worried about duplicates, you'll have to check your DB or S3 server-side anyway when handling the signature request.

Again, Fine Uploader already generates a UUID and uses that as the file name. If you want to verify that whatever name you choose is not in use, you'll need to do that server-side.